# How to format an If Statements with multiple conditionals inside a function

Tags: pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm working on creating a function that will evaluate two conditions from a dataframe and pass a series of prearranged return values given the inputs back to the dataframe should it encounter a NaN. The first condition I'd like to have is a check to see if the value of one column is a NaN (obviously) and then check to another column to see what key the id that has been assigned (1,2,3 etc). The eventual goal is to use the .apply method on the function to fill the NaN values with the values from the function back to the original dataframe or to leave the existing values (if present) alone. What's getting me hung up is that this is the first time I've written anything like this to call within a dataframe and I'm having issue of assignment within the control flow.

This is using python 3.6. I've tried playing around with multiple forms of the below but everything consistently gives me the same type error as it tries to apply the function to the dataframe. This is not the actual dataframe but I made quickly to give you a gist of the issue I'm running into.

Obviously something is off in the function but the result would've ideally updated the NaN value with the 40 value

So far I've tried amending the function in all the ways I can think to make sense to get it to be able to iterate over the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame = {'key' : [1,2,3,4,5],
    'height' : [70, 68, 74, 67, 72],
    'age' : [29,45,'N/A',51,34]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(frame)

frame.replace('N/A',np.nan)

def age (x):
    if (x['age'].isnull()) & (x['key'] == 3):
        return x.replace(np.nan, 40)
    else: 
        return x

result = frame.apply(age)
```

[Here's a snapshot of the dataframe that I would like to amend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nz9v.png)

Comment: any reason why you avoid `.loc[]`? try: `df.loc[(df.age.notnull()) & (df.key == 3), 'age'] = 40`

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-loc/

Comment: I have 3 other conditionals and I just figured this would be the most efficient way considering the size of the df. Sorry I thought I had put this in the OP but just reread and didn't really make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem can be addressed as mentioned below if you really wanted to go with the custom function and apply.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

frame = {'key' : [1,2,3,4,5],
    'height' : [70, 68, 74, 67, 72],
    'age' : [29,45,'N/A',51,34]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(frame)

frame = frame.replace('N/A',np.nan)

#function modified to compare the numpy float value with nan, math library is used here
def age(row):
    if (math.isnan(row['age'])) & (row['key'] == 3):
        return row.replace(np.nan, 40)
    else: 
        return row

result = frame.apply(age, axis=1) #here axis=1 is passing single row at a time to the function
```

input dataframe:

```
key height age
1   70     29.0
2   68     45.0
3   74     NaN
4   67     51.0
5   72     34.0
```

result dataframe:

```
key     height  age
1.0     70.0    29.0
2.0     68.0    45.0
3.0     74.0    40.0
4.0     67.0    51.0
5.0     72.0    34.0
```

I hope this will help you, you can modify the function as per your requirement and modify the datatype of columns.

Comment: Thanks man, worked like a charm, even when I added the other parameters of the IF statement. Gonna have to read up on the "math" library you passed to the environment.